# Flask isn't running externally visible server

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently running a locally hosted website, created in flask as part of a project. I wanted the server to be externally visible, so I checked the docs, and found this:

> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
> accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
> This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
> application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
> you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
> `--host=0.0.0.0` to the command line:
>
> `$ flask run --host=0.0.0.0` This tells your operating system to listen
> on all public IPs.

I assumed the same applied to python, and when started the server like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.debug=True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When running this the terminal said  `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/`, however clicking on that link just gave a "this site can't be reached" error. I tried to go the default address that it normally directed to (127.0. ...) and although this launched the site on my laptop (where flask is running) I still couldn't access the site from other devices on the same network, even when copy-pasting the url.
I also tried typing my laptops ipv4 (192.168. ...) followed by :5000 but still was unable to connect to the server.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Other devices on the network need to go to *your laptop's* local IP address on port 5000, and when the request gets to your laptop it will redirect it to your app which is listening on all IP addresses on port 5000 (it's "bound" to port 5000).

Comment: I should (and now have) clarified that I'd already tried that

Comment: Check the firewall settings on your laptop

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your terminal:

`sudo ufw allow 5000`